# Fire PushNotification in didRangeBeacons methods

Tags: ios, ios7, ibeacon, estimote

I am developing app using Estimote beacons, so i have three beacons one for Entry and second for Exit and third for messages.I want to fire push notification based on proximity user is getting so i get the push notification but issue is that it give multiple same notification.
so i use NSUserDefault to stop multiple pushnotification but it also not works so how can i stop this issue.i also check with local notification but it also give me multiple local notification.

Code:-

```
-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
     didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
            inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region

{
    if ([beacons count] == 0)
        return;

    ESTBeacon* beacon = [beacons firstObject];
    int dist = [beacon.distance intValue];
   if([region.identifier isEqualToString:BeaconIdentifier2]){

       switch (beacon.proximity) {

        case CLProximityUnknown:{

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Far"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Near"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Immediate"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Unknown"] isEqualToString:@"FALSE"])
                {
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"TRUE" forKey:@"Unknown"];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                    NSLog(@"Call Unknown");

                    [self callPush];
                }

            }
                break;

            case CLProximityFar:{

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Unknown"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Near"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Immediate"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Far"] isEqualToString:@"FALSE"])
                {
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"TRUE" forKey:@"Far"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                    //Call webservice
                [self callPush];

                   }

            }
                break;

            case CLProximityNear:{

               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Unknown"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Far"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Immediate"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Near"] isEqualToString: @"FALSE"])
                {
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"TRUE" forKey:@"Near"];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                 //Call webservice
                        [self callPush];

               }
            }
                break;

            case CLProximityImmediate:{

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Unknown"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Far"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"FALSE" forKey:@"Near"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Immediate"] isEqualToString:@"FALSE"])
                {
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"TRUE" forKey:@"Immediate"];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                    //Call webservice
                        [self callPush];

               }
            }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
BOOL isFar=TRUE;
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{

    if (self.beaconRegion) {
        if([beacons count] > 0)
        {
            //get closes beacon and find its major
          CLBeacon *beacon = [beacons objectAtIndex:0];
            switch (beacon.proximity)
            {
                case CLProximityUnknown:
                    break;
                case CLProximityImmediate:
                    NSLog(@"Immediate");

                    if (isFar) {
                        isFar=false;
                       // Call WebService

                    }
                    break;
                case CLProximityNear:
                   if (isFar) {
                      // Call WebService
                  }
                    isFar=false;
                    break;
                case CLProximityFar:
                    NSLog(@"far");
                    if (!isFar) {
                       // call websercie
                   }
                    isFar=TRUE;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: i print with nslog so sometimes beacons found in near range and sometimes is in immediate that why it problem occur.

Comment: Actually the idea is when user goes far we set the flag true and whenever it comes near or immediate then we set flag false and so notification. Now if user stay with near and immediate will not receive notification. and when goes far we get notification

Comment: i use your condition it works but when i come from near to immediate range then immediate notification not works.

Comment: Yes it will not work and better to not to use because near and  immediate is continuously fluctuating. then you will get notification many time.

Comment: yes you are right thanks for help i am accepting you answer cheers :)